# Prevent future date and today date using custom validator

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side-validation, custom-validators

I'm developing a project using **Entity framework** in `.NET 4`. There is a page for sign up which has a field of date of birth. I want to validate it so that date of birth cant be in future or today. Moreover if it could be 5 years back as compared today.

Here is my code.

```
Date of Birth:
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_txtbx_DOB" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtbx_DOB" CssClass="validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Date of Birth Required" SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv_txtbx_DOB" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="txtbx_DOB" CssClass="validator" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="Date of Birth cannot be today or in future" SetFocusOnError="True" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg" ClientValidationFunction="validateDate"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_DOB" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx" Width="200px" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtbx_DOB_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txtbx_DOB" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(sender, args) {
        var currentDate = new Date().getDate();

            if (args.Value < currentDate)
                args.IsValid = true;
            else
                args.IsValid = false;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Here is a uesful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133539/how-can-i-validate-the-date-is-not-the-future-date-in-net-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

```
function check_date()
{
var chkdate = document.getElementById("ID OF YOUR TEXT FIELD HERE").value;

var edate = chkdate.split("/");
var spdate = new Date();
var sdd = spdate.getDate();
var smm = spdate.getMonth();
var syyyy = spdate.getFullYear();
var today = new Date(syyyy,smm,sdd).getTime();
var e_date = new Date(edate[2],edate[1]-1,edate[0]).getTime();
if(e_date > today)
 {
    alert("Date is not valid");
    return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Calendar1.EndDate = DateTime.Now;   //to dissable future  Date
}
```

Here is a link with all the restriction in calendar extender

http://www.karpach.com/ajaxtoolkit-calendar-extender-tweaks.htm

Or use the following java-script function

```
function checkDate(sender, args) {
     if (sender._selectedDate > new Date()) {
          alert("You can select a day earlier than today!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            // set the date back to the current date
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
  }
```

Comment: that's a way around for this but i just want a javascript function without using anything else so that i can reuse it easily. 
The thing that im having problem is how to get a complete date (today with ddmmyyy) and compare it with my control's value. i just wanna restrict young users to sign up. User must be  like 16 years old , and i am not much into javascript or jquery so im really desperate to solve this issue.

Comment: you should not believe the client fully. The java-script will give you the user system date which may not be right. Show it's better to set it from the server side.

Comment: you are right but this is the requirement of client. i can ensure this age constaraint easily on server side but got stuck on client side an error should be shown while filling the form on signup.